# How could Dumbledore see Harry under the Invisibility cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, invisibility-cloak

I've had a look, and while there are many similar questions, they ask about the Marauder's Map or Nagini or some other such magically enhanced object/creature. My question is specifically about Dumbledore, an otherwise ordinary (If very powerful) human wizard.

In Philosopher's Stone, Dumbledore looks directly at Harry and Ron in Hagrid's hut. The Invisibility Cloak is supposedly able to hide the wearer from Death himself and yet Dumbledore just looked right into their eyes like the cloak wasn't there.

I can't think how he was able to do that. Was it a spell? Or is he so awesome that he can psychically just know?

Comment: Not sure whether this is close enough to duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16888/51379

Comment: Ah, Homenum Revelio, is it? So it was a spell. Dumbledore IS a master of non-verbal spell casting.

Comment: Nonverbal *and* probably wandless

Comment: @Obie2.0 Appears to be duplicate because that answer does answer this question

Comment: @Aegon - I've tried to be a bit more conservative about closing as duplicate since reading [Shog's answer here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9748/51379).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked this question in particular. I'll admit I didn't notice about that answer talking about Homenum Revelio, but I did specify that I already knew about the Map, Nagini and Moody, because they were all magically enhanced in some way and granted the extra detection capability they needed to see the cloak. Dumbledore has no such extra object, he has regular human eyes. So I was wondering about specifically Dumbledore.

Comment: I guess you can close this as a duplicate question, provided that anybody who wonders about Dumbledore in particular (like I did) can get redirected to the correct answer that they're looking for (like I did). It's a bit weird to have to look up Mad-Eye Moody to get an answer relating to Dumbledore, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Maybe you would like to add that bit as an answer here (With credit and link to the original answerer of course) as a community wiki?

Comment: Sounds good, I have done that. Should I still click "That solved my problem" and mark this as a dupe now? I'm unsure of the policy in this situation.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Since your question was completely solved just by quoting from the other answer, I closed it as a duplicate. +1 to your question and answer though :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17008/54887) by [Slytherincess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/slytherincess) to [Why could Madeye Moody/Barty Crouch see through the Invisibility Cloak using his Magical Eye?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16888/why-could-madeye-moody-barty-crouch-see-through-the-invisibility-cloak-using-his)

We know for certain that at least one spell works against the Invisibility Cloak: Homenum Revelio. In Chamber of Secrets, Dumbledore uses Homenum Revelio to see Harry and Ron under the Invisibility Cloak in Hagrid's hut:

> ‘However,’ said Dumbledore, speaking very slowly and clearly, so that none of them could miss a word, ‘you will find that I will only truly have left this school when none here are loyal to me. You will also find that help will always be given at Hogwarts to those who ask for it.’
>
> For a second, Harry was almost sure Dumbledore’s eyes flickered towards the corner where he and Ron stood hidden.
>
> <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 195 - UK Hardcover - chapter 14, *Cornelius Fudge*</sub>

J.K. Rowling confirms this in an interview:

> Angela Morrissey: Why is it that albus dumbledore can see harry under his invisibility cloak at certain moments? (during the series is the cloak only infallible to those who do not own a deathly hallow).
>
> J.K. Rowling: Dumbledore, who could perform magic without needing to say the incantation aloud, was using ‘homenum revelio’ - the human-presence-revealing spell Hermione makes use of in Deathly Hallows.

Comment: The question follows then, how did he know they were there to use that spell? Or does he always just use it to know what's going on?

Comment: "Or does he always just use it to know what's going on?" Looks like he just casts it randomly, just in case.